# What would be the best possible way to generate API keys and hash passwords in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I am using my own authentication and sort of worried about the present security of my API. What would you suggest would be a good way to generate API keys? And what would be a better way to hash the password?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For api keys I would suggest you node-uuid. For hashing passwords - builtin crypto. For api secrets you can also use node-uuid + crypto combined. Something like that (node repl):

```
> require('node-uuid')()
'5d2962e4-55c8-460c-aa7b-9586905779cb'
> require('crypto').createHash('sha256').update(_).update('salt').digest('hex');
'06f905820cafb3b34bd7ba8729acf6d671446ff09ffb0aaa7f0290c936fc6c68'
```

Comment: +1 I was thinking to write the very same, before seeing your answer :)

Comment: Simple is better, almost always :)

Comment: with crypto salt - `crypto.createHash('sha256').update(uuid.v4()).update(crypto.randomBytes(256)).digest('hex')`

Comment: I would store passwords with a cryptographic hash with a built-in per-user salt like bcrypt, scrypt or Argon2, all of which there are node packages for.

Comment: @Beau Those are all **password** hashing functions and none of those hashes are suitable for API keys, which are not passwords. SHA256 is the correct choice.

Comment: @meagar I totally agree, that's why I said I would store passwords with one of those functions, which was the 2nd question the OP asked. SHA-256 is absolutely not the correct answer for that part of the question.

Comment: @Beau You're absolutely right, I missed the last part of the question.